# C# Set property to an object in Dictionary list - Why NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, dictionary, nullreferenceexception

This is my first question.

I have this code in my Forms App. I don't understand why i always get an NullReferenceException.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   Dictionary<string, Product> ProductList = new Dictionary<string, Product>();

   public Form1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();

      Product product = new Product();
      Position position = new Position();
      product.Name = "ACAD";
      position.Name = "Industry";

      ProductList.Add(product.Name, product);

      // NullReferenceException:
      ProductList["ACAD"].PositionList.Add(position.Name, position);

      // Following line works:
      //listBox1.Items.Add(ProductList["ACAD"]);
   }
}

class Product
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string, Position> PositionList { get; set; }
}

class Position
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you =)

Comment: Someone has to initialize `Product.PositionList` (`= new Dictionary...`)

Comment: PositionList  is null, so the NullReferenceException `Product product = new Product(); product.Name = "ACAD"; product.PositionList=new Dictionary<string, Position>();`

Comment: change `class Product` so that `PositionList` is initialized.  You could write `public var PositionList = new Dictionary<string, Position>()`

Comment: Thank you guys.. Sorry I'm still learning

Comment: If you [Use the debugger](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn), it is easy to tell what is null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constructor for your product class:

```
class Product
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string, Position> PositionList { get; set; }

   public Product()
   {
      PositionList = new Dictionary<string, Position>();
   }
}
```

And you can avoid the null reference exception from trying to add an entry to your null dictionary: `ProductList["ACAD"].PositionList.Add(position.Name, position);`